# How to sort the jqGrid without considering the last blank row

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvcjqgrid

I have a **jqGrid** where there is a blank row added in the end.

I need to sort the grid without considering the last blank row.

How can I achieve ?
Kindly help.

[image]

Comment: please check my ans and let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give some id to blank row say -1.
On LoadComplete function check for blank row id is present or not before adding.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the last blank row before sort and then sort. here is my code please let me know if it solve your problem.

```
/* button Click */
$('.yourButton').click(function(){

        /* get all rows */
        var row =  $('#jqxgrid').actGrid('getrows');

        /* get the last row */
        var datarow = $("#jqxgrid").actGrid('getrowdata', row.length-1);
        if(datarow.Id){ /* check weather last row is blank or not */
            /* if blank then delete */
            $('#jqxgrid').actGrid('deleterow', row.length-1);
        }    
        /* sort the gris */
        $("#jqxgrid").actGrid('sortby', 'FieldName', 'desc');

});
```